# Deleting all rows from table, and resetting auto incrementation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

code is below. Seems like when I run this file, it doesn't do anything.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "friendslist");
if($DB->connect_errno) {
    die("Connect failed: ". $DB->connect_error);
}

$DB->query("DELETE * FROM users");
$DB->query("ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");

$DB->close();

    echo json_encode(Array('status' => 'ok'));
```

Comment: you should use TRUNCATE not delete

Comment: you should check for errors from `$DB->query()`.

Comment: `DELETE * FROM users` is a syntax error. It should just be `DELETE FROM users`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query has incorrect syntax. If you read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html), you'll see that the valid syntaxes of `DELETE` are either:

```
DELETE FROM users
```

or:

```
DELETE users.* FROM users
```

where `.*` is optional in the second version. But `DELETE *` is not valid.

You could also just use `TRUNCATE tablename` to delete everything from the table and reset the auto increment ID in one step.

You should also check whether queries succeed:

```
$DB->query("DELETE * FROM users") or die ($DB->error);
```

would have told you that there was a syntax error. Then I'm sure you would have checked the documentation to see what the correct syntax is, and fixed it right away, rather than going the slow route of posting a question to SO.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your delete systex is wrong which is generating error for your code.

Secondly, you should use truncate instead of delete as they work in two different approach.

`TRUNCATE TABLE tablename;` actually drops and recreate the table so its fast and it reset the auto increment seed value to 1.

Whereas, `DELETE FROM tablename;` deletes all the data in the table. It is not as quick as using the "TRUNCATE TABLE" method and it left auto increment seed value as it was before.

So you can use the following:

```
if($DB->query("TRUNCATE TABLE users"))
    echo json_encode(Array('status' => 'ok'));
else  echo json_encode(Array('status' => $DB->error));
```

You will get the problem from the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove `*` from your **delete query**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "friendslist");
if($DB->connect_errno) {
    die("Connect failed: ". $DB->connect_error);
}

$DB->query("DELETE FROM users");// Remove * from here
$DB->query("ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");

$DB->close();

    echo json_encode(Array('status' => 'ok'));
```